# cannot use vcpkg to download C++ libraries in Windowsx64 Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

I just installed VSCode on Windows to start using it as my first IDE. However, putting some basic programs in there, I noticed it (unlike another IDE I was using) does not have any libraries for C++ whatsoever.

`#include <iostream>` for example has a problem, and when I click it it says to go download vcpkg to download the libraries. I followed the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019 to install it but when I try to use `vcpkg search` in the command line it does nothing. Is there any way to use vcpkg with VSCode? Running the .bat file as directed does nothing. I just want to get these libraries in so my programs I've already written will work and I can add new libraries as I need/learn them. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed the instructions exactly, and when I search online there are no other helpful results.

Comment: VSCode is just an editor. It doesn't come with compiler or libraries. You should probably get Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Your standard library headers should come with your compiler. VSCode doesn't come with a compiler, so you'll have to install one yourself. Here are the instructions for Mingw-w64: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw This has nothing to do with vcpkg.

Answer (score 0):

I ran that line with forward slashes instead of backslashes and it did something, FYI:

$ ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
Downloading https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/2022-09-20/vcpkg.exe -> C:\Users\me\vcpkg.exe... done.
Validating signature... done.

### Telemetry

vcpkg collects usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data collected by Microsoft is anonymous.
You can opt-out of telemetry by re-running the bootstrap-vcpkg script with -disableMetrics,
passing --disable-metrics to vcpkg on the command line,
or by setting the VCPKG_DISABLE_METRICS environment variable.

Read more about vcpkg telemetry at docs/about/privacy.md